# Как исправить ошибки "Контент шире экрана", "Интерактивные элементы расположены слишком близко"?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, google-search, google-services

В последнее время почти на всех моих сайтах при проверке на сервисе https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly у многих моих сайтов появились одинаковые ошибки "Контент шире экрана", "Интерактивные элементы расположены слишком близко".

При этом тестирование верстки не дает никаких "зацепок", что конкретно не нравится сервису - страницы отображаются корректно, горизонтальных скролов нет, навигация удобная (межстрочные интервалы, отступы и т.п.).

Есть подозрение, что проблема в какой-то особенности методологии проверки, про которую я не знаю. Скриншоты, которые снимает сервис с сайтов в момент тестирования, почему-то без CSS-стилей - просто разметка.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом.

Comment: Проверьте это руководство Гугл Основы отзывчивого веб-дизайна - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/ .

Comment: Если возможно, то конкретизируйте ваш вопрос. В настоящее время это только абстрактная информация.